# SELinux context of files mounted from a Solaris server

Tags: linux, mount, solaris, nfs, selinux

Something I'm attempting to run in `RHEL 6` fails as a result of SELinux.  The problem is temporarily easily solved with `setenforce 0`.  However turning SELinux off entirely isn't an option in my case.

The problem is that these files are mounted from an old Solaris machine, and the context of everything loaded is **system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0**.  I need to modify just a handful of files that are mounted from that machine to **httpd_sys_content_t.**

Any attempt to do this, however, results in "**Operation not supported**".  The command I am attempting to use is:

**`chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/my/stuff`**

From what I can tell, this is because everything from that server is mounted as **system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0**.  Being Solaris, I can't go to the machine itself and use chcon, as SELinux and chcon don't exist.

The solution I can think of that will work is to just install the same software on this machine, which is `RHEL 6`, cutting Solaris out all together.  I'd like to know if that is my only choice or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options (within SELinux) exist:

1) All else fails `audit2allow` can convert any SELinux denials into allowed operation.

2) What I would recommend: Enable the SELinux boolean for allowing `httpd_t` to access `nfs_t` objects:

```
[root@ditirlns02 ~]# getsebool httpd_use_nfs
httpd_use_nfs --> off
[root@ditirlns02 ~]# setsebool -P httpd_use_nfs=1
[root@ditirlns02 ~]# getsebool httpd_use_nfs
httpd_use_nfs --> on
[root@ditirlns02 ~]#
```

Security contexts are set by the machine that mounts the remote filesystem, so Solaris is largely unrelated. Even if the exports were coming from RHEL the NFS exports are still going to be `nfs_t` and there's not much you can do about that

Comment: Number 2 worked perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: Right, but why weren't you able to change the SELinux context? Maybe should've tried `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t /mounted/on/local/dir`

Comment: I guess maybe the remote program would need access to resources/locations that were not already allowed to the httpd service.

Comment: File contexts are stored with inode information, in ext3/4 this is an "extended attribute". For network filesystems like AFS, NFS, SMBfs, etc there is no metadata to store individual file's context information. The best SELinux can do is segregate by network filesystem type.